# accessing values using multiple relationships with NSPredicate

Tags: iphone, core-data, nspredicate

here is my core data model:

Locations < --- >> ThemesList << --- > Themes

The entites have the following attributes:

Locations
- Property: Name
- Relationship: ThemesList

ThemesList
- Relationship: Locations
- Relationship: Themes

Themes
- Property: Name
- Relationship: Locations

I am running a fetch on entity Locations and I want to only pull values where the name property in Themes is equal to a particular value.  Based on what I've read, I need to do a subquery.  I've tried something along the lines of the code below, but I always receive the error of *Unable to parse the format string*

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(ThemesList, $theThemes, $theThemes.Themes.Name LIKE %@)", @"a theme name"];
```

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this - what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, you should fetch the objects of the entity you are testing with the predicate instead of starting with another entity altogether and walking a relationship inside the predicate. Walking relationships, especially to-many relationships inside of predicates is computationally intensive and slow.

Instead, I would recommend running the fetch against the `Theme` entity and then just ask the returned `Theme` objects for their associated `Locations` objects.

Your predicate would simplify to just:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Themes.Name LIKE %@", @"a theme name"];
```

Then use a collection operator to find the location objects:

```
NSSet *locations=[fetchedThemes valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfSets.locations"];
```

Comment: Thanks TechZen, this worked out.  I also found that I needed to include single quotes around the '%@' in order to have the comparison parse correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this:  `$theThemes.Themes.Name`.  The parser will want to parse it as a variable expression (since it starts with a `$`), but when it comes across the `.`, it's going to produce an error.

As it turns out, the `SUBQUERY` is unnecessary.  That same query can be effectively done as:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY ThemesList.Themes.Name LIKE %@", @"a theme name"];
```

Hopefully Core Data will have an easier time handling that than the `SUBQUERY`.